# bitbake conditional inclusion of depends statement

Tags: python, bitbake

How do I include a depends line in a bitbake file with a condition ?
I want something like below:

```
if (some env varible)
  DEPENDS += "recipe-1"
else
  DEPENDS += "recipe-2'
```

I have tried below in the .bb file:

```
DEPENDS += "${@ 'recipe-2' if '${ENV_VAR}' else 'recipe-1'}"
```

Before that I exported ENV_VAR to BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE

```
export BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE="$BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE ENV_VAR"
```

This is working only when ENV_VAR is set:

```
env ENV_VAR="value" bitbake test-recipe
```

if ENV_VAR is not set, it is throwing an error while parsing the bitbake DEPENDS line

```
ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable DEPENDS, expression was
${@ 'recipe-2' if '${ENV_VAR}' else 'recipe-1'}  
which triggered exception SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (DEPENDS, line 1)
```

Comment: Does it deal with python ?

Comment: I am using the python expressions in bitbake.

    DEPENDS += "${@ 'recipe-2' if '${ENV_VAR}' else 'recipe-1'}"

    Syntax:DEPENDS += "${@ python expression}"

Comment: `recipe-2' if '${ENV_VAR}' else 'recipe-1` is not a correct python expression as `${ENV_VAR}` returns the value of `ENV_VAR` in a shell. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
DEPENDS += "${@ 'recipe-2' if d.getVar('ENV_VAR') else 'recipe-1'}"
```

The reason why is that `${ENV_VAR}` gets expanded to the value of the variable. If its unset, it doesn't get expanded and that triggers the error you see. By using `getVar` you get a result which the rest of the python expression can deal with `None` or a value.

Note that there are some proposed changes which might improve the behaviour to make this a bit more usable and understandable to people but the above would continue to work regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have recipes, recipe-main & recipe-test and based on the value of `USE_TEST_RECIPE` `0` or `1`, you can do the following

`DEPENDS_append += "${@base_conditional('USE_TEST_RECIPE', '1', 'recipe-test', 'recipe-main', d)}"`

Comment: Use `oe.utils.conditional` for newer yocto releases.